# Adding tabs on elementor

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, elementor

I am looking to add tabs to my activity packs, categorized by different themes. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? I want to organize the packs more efficiently and provide a better user experience for our users. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Please see it here: https://rainbowsmart.co.uk/free-printable-learning-worksheets/